# Data has not been inserted into database (using SqlDataSource)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I am not able to pass values entered in form into database in ASP.NET. I have two DropDownList controls, two TextBox controls and 1 html control with FILE input type. This is my code:

This is my design page:

```
<asp:Content ID="ContentCitizenProfile" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="cpdCitizenProfile">

<asp:ScriptManager ID="smDDL" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upDDL" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
     <div class="form-inline" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
<asp:Label ID="lblCType" runat="server" Text="Complaint Type:"/>  
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCType" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Comp_Type" DataValueField="Type_ID" AutoPostBack="True" ondatabound="DDLCTypeDataBound" style="margin-left:79px" >
</asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ComplaintWebsiteConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Complaint_Type]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RfvDDLCompType" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Select Complaint Type" ControlToValidate="ddlCType" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
     </div>


<div class="form-inline" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
    <asp:Label ID="lblSubType" runat="server" Text="Complaint Sub Type:"/>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubType" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Comp_SubType" DataValueField="Type_ID" ondatabound="DDLSubTypeDataBound" style="margin-left:50px">
</asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ComplaintWebsiteConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Complaint_SubType] WHERE ([Type_ID] = @Type_ID2)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlCType" Name="Type_ID2" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvDDlSubType" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Select Complaint Sub Type" ControlToValidate="ddlSubType" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>       

<div id="demo" class="form-inline" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
    <asp:Label ID="lblLocation" runat="server" Text="Location:"/>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLoc" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" style="margin-left:120px"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
    <button ID="lblFind" runat="server" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Find location on map</button>
    <br/><br />
    <iframe src="CompLocation.html" height="300" width="600"></iframe>
    </div>


<div class="form-inline" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
    <asp:Label ID="lblDesc" runat="server" Text="Post Description:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesc" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" style="margin-left:70px"></asp:TextBox>
</div>

<div class="form-inline" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
    <asp:Label ID="lblFileUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload Image:" style="margin-right:86px"/>
    <input id="UpldFile" type="file" class="filestyle btn-info" data-iconName="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox" style="margin-right:20px"/>
  <img id="imgPreview" src="#" alt="" style="width:150px;height:150px" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
```

```
<div class="form-inline" style="margin-bottom:50px;">
<button id="btnReportComp" class="btn btn-success" onserverclick="btnPostComp">Report Complaint</button> 
<button id="btnReset" class="btn btn-danger" onserverclick="btnReset" style="margin-left:20px">Reset</button>
</div>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceReport" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ComplaintWebsiteConnectionString %>" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO Citizen_Complaints(Comp_Type, Comp_SubType, Location, Description, Image) VALUES (@ctype,@subtype,@loc,@desc,@img)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Citizen_Complaints]">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlCType" Name="ctype" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlSubType" Name="subtype" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtLoc" Name="loc" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtDesc" Name="desc" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:FormParameter FormField="UpldFile" Name="img" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

.cs page:

```
protected void btnReportComp(object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSourceReport.Insert();
    }
```

Comment: No error. But the database columns are empty

Comment: have you add this `InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure"` inside `<asp:SqlDataSource` also try to put try catch while doing insert operation.

Comment: @rajeshpanchal here is no any stored procedure. She formed her question not correctly. I edited the question, nobody approved it yet.

Comment: I think you should add `try..catch` to get the exception. that will more helpful to find the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleted sqldatasource and added to the button next click method:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Utils.Connection);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("citizen_complaints_i", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TYPE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlCType.SelectedValue;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SUBTYPE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlSubType.SelectedValue;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LOCATION", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtLoc.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DESCRIPTION", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtDesc.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@IMAGE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Utils.file_upload(fuImage);

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //...
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your InsertCommand to the following:

```
INSERT INTO Citizen_Complaints(Comp_Type, Comp_SubType, Location, Description, Image) VALUES (@ctype,@subtype,@loc,@desc,@img)
```

Comment: Did. But still the columns are null

Comment: @Ashwini I think this is because of your image. Post your design code

Comment: @Ashwini Change your html image input control to asp:FileUpload control, and then send FileUpload1.FileName to your database. I think you have varchar field in your database to store the file name, but your code try to send the whole image to your database. But your code not so clear... I would like to help to make it much more effective and looking well

Comment: I have applied Css and js to file upload so I have used input type. And I have kept the image to allow nulls in db. So I checked without inputting the image but the other values are also not passed to db